# Colour of artifacts in a lens flare

Tags: lenses

I'm adding a lens flare to an illustration; which got me thinking:
Are the colours of the  artifacts (hexagonal/circular) which appear in a lens flares purely random, or much like a rainbow (predictable and ordered)?

[image]